# Print[] text in the style of Message[]

Tags: warning-messages, style, text-formatting

I would like to imitate the aesthetic style of `Message[]` text, but using `Print[]`, and customising the colour. The output I desire is close to:

[image]

but I wish to change the colour of the `myFunc:` prefix, from red to (e.g.) orange.

Sadly `Echo[]` uses a different font and message-text colour:

[image]

I can get close using `Print[]` and `Style[]`, but haven't worked out the text size and font-family of `Message`:

```
Print[ Style["myFunc: ", Orange], Style["Please ignore the preceding error", Gray] ]
```

[image]

How can I precisely imitate `Message` style using `Print[]`?

Comment: Select message's cell, hit Ctrl+Shift+E to see what's behind it

Comment: It revealed use of `TemplateBox`, but seemingly without *all* the styling; it suggests, in place of `Print[]`, to use `DisplayForm @ TemplateBox[{"myFunc", "err", 
  "Please ignore the preceding error."}, "MessageTemplate"]` but alas this yields a different font than `Message[]` (and gives no clues about changing the colour)

Comment: @Kuba Ah wrapping my `TemplateBox` in `Cell[BoxData[..., "Message", "MSG"]` renders just like `Message[]`, but still leaves me clueless as to how to change the colour of the 'myFunc: ' prefix

Comment: Why not Quiet the offending message instead?

Comment: Not appropriate for my use-case (the example text you see above is mostly placeholder)